# Using HP Quality Centre 10 from Java

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, j-integra

I am trying to connect to HP QC 10 from Java+jIntegra with the following code:

```
System.setProperty("JINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE", ""); 

TDConnection connection = new TDConnection();
System.out.println("TDConnection object created");

connection.initConnectionEx("http://myserver:8080/qcbin/");
System.out.println("Connection initialized");

connection.login("user", "pass");
System.out.println("Logged in");

connection.connect("domain", "project");
System.out.println("Connected");

System.out.println(connection.isConnected());
```

All looks fine until I call connection.isConnected(), which causes the JVM to crash:

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0b1d3cfc, pid=24452, tid=24052
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b22 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntvinv.dll+0x13cfc]
```

The error report file doesn't show anything meaningful as far as I can see.
Unfortunately I cannot use QC11, so no way to use RESTful APIs.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks,
Marco